# Is this Q&A in scope of this stackexchange?

Tags: support

Is [this Q&A](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/3511/210) in scope of this stackexchange site?

On one hand it could be the case as, but on the other hand it is really about how to create a graph based on database records. From the latter perspective, it could be out of scope.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the post

Comment: Is it completely DevOps to you or do you have some suggestions to improve it more? I still feel it could be fine-tuned a little bit more.